# running package in console spyder not possible

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

After finishing installing scrapy in console with:
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy

I'm not able to use any scrapy commands such as "scrapy -h".
When using the Anaconda Powershell everything is working.

Is the console in Spyder something different than the Anaconda powershell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that spyder is using a different version or installation of Python than anaconda.

In both the spyder console and anaconda powershell run:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)
```

If both don't produce the same output, that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Both have the same paths. I found out that the spyder console is in a Python environment, in Anaconda I'm at the base level. Only at the base level I can run Scrapy. Once I enter the Python environment, I'm not able to use Scrapy anymore.

Comment: Do you mean a *virtual environment*? That would definitely explain the problem.

Comment: No, when you type "Python" in the powershell and press enter